# Android - margin between AutoCompleteTextView dropdown and soft input keyboard

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, window-soft-input-mode

With `window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` I was able to prevent the dropdown of my AutoCompleteTextView from going behind the soft input keyboard, but it is now flush against the keyboard as shown in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOT5.jpg):
[image]

Is there a way to add a margin between the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown and the soft input keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Add dropdown height to your autocomplete textview in xml as `android:dropDownHeight="100dp"`

Comment: There would be excess space if I hardcode the dropDownHeight instead of doing wrap_content when there's only 1 or 2 items to show in the dropdown,

Comment: You can set dropdown height dynamically based on number of items as `autoCompletetxtView.setDropDownHeight(int);`

Comment: To do this effectively, I'd have to determine how many items will be displayed in the dropdown at a given moment. I don't think there's a way to do get this information.